# Android Orange outline does not move on autoTab

Tags: android, focus

I am using Javascript to autoTab between input elements when max length is reached 
        obj.focus();
        obj.select();

The cursor moves to the next element and user can enter text but the orange highlight outline does not move, it stays on the previous input element. 
This seems to be an issue only on Android 2.1, works fine, on other versions of Android and on iPhone.

How do I make the orange focus outline move as well ?